# Имя прилагательное

Tags: этимология, прилагательные

Потребность обозначить признаки предметов появилась у человека давно.

Какая из этих форм прилагательного является древнейшей?

меньше

малейший

мала

маленькая

малая

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем примере - это краткая форма прилагательного "мал" Т.к. исторически первичной является краткая форма. Она была более древняя и от нее образовывались полные формы путем присоединения к ним падежных форм указательного местоимения.

Comment: А «меньше» это тот же корень?

Comment: И ещё: "меньше" и "менять" - однокоренные?

Comment: Это разные корни.